# Animating element onClick with GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, onclick, gatsby

I am having trouble getting an animation to work properly onClick.
On this site: https://cranky-hamilton-77d147.netlify.app/game/ I am attempting to animate the card deck shuffling and the spinner wheel rotating while a new random set of card content is rendered, all on one click of the spinner wheel.

Currently, when you click on the spinner enough times, the two animations are out of sync. I believe this is an issue with how I'm setting state to true or false but have been unable to get it working properly.

```
export default () => {
  const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0)
  const getRandomCardIndexBetween = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(max) - Math.ceil(min) + 1)) + min

  const [isClicked, setAnim] = useState(false);
  const toggleAnim = () => {
    setAnim(!isClicked);
    console.log(isClicked);

    return () => {
      setAnim(!isClicked);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql` 
          query TopicFeed {
              allContentfulTopic(filter: {featured: {eq: true}}) {
                  edges {
                      node {
                          cardDescription {
                              cardDescription
                          }
                          cardTitle
                          id
                          slug
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      `}
      render={data => ( 
        <div>
          <section id="topic-section">
            <div className='feed'>
            <ul className='topic__item--stack'>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
            </ul>

              {data.allContentfulTopic.edges.map((edge, index) => index === cardIndex
                ? (
                  <div key={edge.node.id} className='topic__item draw-card--anim'>
                    <h2 className='card__title'>{edge.node.cardTitle}</h2>
                    <div className="card__desc--container">
                      <p className='card__desc'>{edge.node.cardDescription.cardDescription}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='card__link' onClick={() => navigate(`/topic/${edge.node.slug}`)}>
                      <p>Learn More</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : null)}
            </div>
            <div className="spin-wheel--container" onClick={toggleAnim}>
                <div className={isClicked ? 'spin-wheel--anim' : ''} onClick={() => setCardIndex(getRandomCardIndexBetween(0, data.allContentfulTopic.edges.length - 1))}>   
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="spin-wheel" viewBox="0 0 401.1 401">
                        <title>spin-wheel</title>
                        <path id="space8" class="cls-1" d="M59 342l47.9-47.9C64.4 248.9 68.2 200.5 68.2 200.5L0.5 200.8S-3.2 281 59 342Z"/>
                        <path id="space6" class="cls-2" d="M342 59l-47.9 48C336.6 152.1 332.8 200.5 332.8 200.5l67.7-0.3S404.2 120 342 59Z"/>
                        <path id="space5" class="cls-3" d="M59 59l47.9 48C64.4 152.1 68.2 200.5 68.2 200.5L0.5 200.2S-3.2 120 59 59Z"/>
                        <path id="space4" class="cls-4" d="M59 59l48 47.9C152.1 64.4 200.5 68.2 200.5 68.2L200.2 0.5S120-3.2 59 59Z"/>
                        <path id="space3" class="cls-5" d="M59 342l48-47.9C152.1 336.6 200.5 332.8 200.5 332.8L200.2 400.5S120 404.2 59 342Z"/>
                        <path id="space2" class="cls-6" d="M342 342l-47.9-47.9C248.9 336.6 200.5 332.8 200.5 332.8l0.3 67.7S281 404.2 342 342Z"/>
                        <path id="space1" class="cls-7" d="M342 59l-47.9 47.9C248.9 64.4 200.5 68.2 200.5 68.2L200.8 0.5S281-3.2 342 59Z"/>
                        <path id="space8-2" data-name="space8" class="cls-8" d="M400.5 200.7h-67.8c-1.8 62.1-38.8 93.6-38.8 93.6l48.1 47.6S401.5 287.8 400.5 200.7Z"/>
                        <circle class="cls-9" cx="200.5" cy="200.5" r="200"/>
                        <circle class="cls-9 white-fill" cx="200.5" cy="200.5" r="132.7"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Also, I am wondering if there is a better way I should be handling animations in the first place. Any best practices for these animations with gatsby/react would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `setTimeOut function`, that you can passed to `OnClick Method` so it will disable the spinner and it will activated it only after the animation ends running, something like this:

```js
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
const ANIM_TIME = 1000;

function spinWheel() {
  setDisabled(true);
  setCardIndex(getRandomCardIndexBetween(0, data.allContentfulTopic.edges.length - 1))};
  setTimeout(() => setDisabled(false), ANIM_TIME)
}
```

then you passed the `disabled state` the card component disallowing to users hang clicking it and messed up with your state, also I would recommend using the tag `button` for binding the Onclick function